# Garbage after reading a large text file using (FILE*)

Tags: c, file, fread

I have a sample program written in C/C++, which reads a text file into memory. While trying to parse this file (not part of this sample), I came across lots of garbage near end of file. Investigating this I found there is some problem while reading large files into memory; this problem does not happen with small sized text files. Here is my code:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

char* readFile_(char* fname)
{
    char* rv=NULL;
    int bytes=0;
    FILE* pfile = NULL;
    pfile = fopen( fname, "r" );
    if ( pfile )
    {
        fseek(pfile, 0, SEEK_END);
        bytes = ftell(pfile);
        fseek(pfile, 0, SEEK_SET);
        rv = new char[bytes+1];
        memset(rv,0,bytes+1);
        fread( rv, bytes, 1, pfile );
        fclose(pfile);
    }
    return rv;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char* filebuffer = NULL;
    filebuffer = readFile_( "mv2.txt" );

    FILE* pfile = fopen("op.txt", "w");
    int len = strlen(filebuffer);
    fwrite( filebuffer, len, 1, pfile );
    fclose(pfile);

    delete[] filebuffer;
    return 0;
}
```

For reference, files are hosted here:

mv2.txt file: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bb101393729d3ada944f 
op.txt file: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/93595c83ad62e40d0f0a

Can anyone highlight what seems to be the problem?

Edit: I am using Windows (Windows 7 OS)

Edit 2: Thanks everyone for helping me find the problem, here is the updated code based on few of your feedbacks that seems to solve my problem even for some very large text files:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

char* readFile_(char* fname)
{
    char* rv=NULL;
    long bytes=0;
    FILE* pfile = NULL;
    pfile = fopen( fname, "rb" );
    if ( pfile )
    {
        fseek(pfile, 0, SEEK_END);
        bytes = ftell(pfile);
        fseek(pfile, 0, SEEK_SET);
        rv = new char[bytes+1];
        memset(rv,0,bytes+1);
        fread( rv, bytes, 1, pfile );
        fclose(pfile);
    }
    return rv;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char* filebuffer = NULL;
    filebuffer = readFile_( "mv2.txt" );

    FILE* pfile = fopen("op.txt", "wb");
    int len = strlen(filebuffer);
    fwrite( filebuffer, len, 1, pfile );
    fclose(pfile);

    delete[] filebuffer;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: YOu need to decide what language you are using. `C` and `C++` are different languages. Looks to me that you are using `C++` but you are including the `C` libraries. In `C++` code you should include `<cstdlib>`, `<cstdio>` and `<cstring>` for the `C++` verisons.

Comment: Dude - check the error returns for all of your I/O = "fseek()",  "fread()", etc! Be sure to handle any potentional "new" allocation failures (or use C "malloc()" instead, and check for NULL).

Comment: Try opening the file in binary ("rb") mode. The results of ftell are not guaranteed to be meaningful on files opened in character mode.

Comment: Does this exact code exhibit the error for you? because it appears to work for me copying the file unchanged.

Comment: Here's [a lot of information on how to do this safely](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/FIO19-C.+Do+not+use+fseek%28%29+and+ftell%28%29+to+compute+the+size+of+a+regular+file).

Comment: @ Galik, yes this exact code with mv2.txt file hosted online exhibits this problem

Comment: @ Chris DuPuis, you are right, not using "rb" mode seemed to be the problem in my case ... but then I also need to use "wb" to write file back on disk - this solved the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By including conio.h, I can make the assumption you are on Windows.  In Windows, you will encounter problems in situations like this without using binary mode reads.  I would try opening the file with "rb" as the mode.

```
FILE* pfile = NULL;
pfile = fopen( fname, "rb" );
```

Comment: You are right, not using "rb" mode seemed to be the problem in my case ... but then I also need to use "wb" to write file back on disk - this solved the problem!

Comment: Excellent!  :) I'm glad my answer worked for you!  Not sure you mean to accept the answer below?

Comment: To be completely clear, the difference is that, in Windows, binary mode is not default (as it is on POSIX systems).

Comment: Technically posix doesn't make binary by default - there is simply no difference between binary and text.  ;) In Windows there are actually good reasons for non-binary mode -- since windows a long time ago decided to treat line endings "uniquely" (e.g. \r\n instead of \n).  Non binary (text) mode makes windows internally deal with their "special" line endings - and translate on output for you automatically.  But, yes, in general binary mode is what you will need.

Comment: I have file opened with binary read, and i am still seeing this problem.